# Wordpress Weekly Class Schedule Plugin not showing correct timezone

Tags: wordpress, plugins, calendar, timezone

I have installed the weekly class schedule plugin on this website: https://www.familienzentrum-weissensee.de/
Since a few days, the timezone I set in wordpress is not recognized anymore. Unfortunately the plugin provider is not following up anymore on the forum and I was wondering if someone got the same problem over here.
I don't want to mess with the code before understanding what's going on but I can provide more detail if needed.
Thank you for your help!

I tried changing the timezone but this obv didn't work..

Comment: WordPress support forum post for reference:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/calendar-time-is-not-working-in-the-right-timezone-anymore/

Comment: Can you please clarify what the issue is? I installed the plugin, and I do not see any use of timezones.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!The issue is that on every calendar and on the editing page, the time is this: https://www.familienzentrum-weissensee.de and if I click let's say on the event: Yoga (which is at 2:30 AM on the home page) it is at 6:30pm on the event page, which is the real time. https://www.familienzentrum-weissensee.de/class/yoga/?wcs_timestamp=1686076200

Comment: What are the shortcodes on the frontpage and on `/class/yoga/`?

Comment: This is the front page shortcode: [vc-wcs-schedule id="10"] and the class/yoga doesn't have one from what I see, it's a class page built with bakery page builder

Comment: Ahh, that means the plugin's code for output is probably irrelevant.